# Peekmessage (creating window loop)

Tags: c++, windows

Igot this error and I don't know why, I just follow correctly what he do, and he doesn't get this error. Here is the code.

```
 //Main application loop
        MSG msg = {0};
        while(WM_QUIT != msg.message())
        {
            if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_Remove))
            {
                //Translate message
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                
                //Dispatch message
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
```

And here are the error:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

And when I clicked it, they all pointing to the while loop.

Answer (score 8):

The `message` member of the [MSG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958.aspx) structure is a field, not a method. You should access it instead of calling it:

```
while (WM_QUIT != msg.message) {
    // ...
}
```

There are other issues in your code snippet. First, C++ is a case-sensitive language, so the last argument to `PeekMessage()` should be `PM_REMOVE` instead of `PM_Remove`.

In addition, [PeekMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx) does not block if the message queue is empty, so your code will end up consuming 100% of the CPU core it runs on. You can use [GetMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) instead, which blocks if no message is available and would allow you to remove the explicit test for `WM_QUIT`:

```
MSG msg = { 0 };
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Comment: His code will burn 100% core

Comment: @Hans, I was wondering if it was by design, but you're right, this is worth pointing out.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) suggests to use `while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0)` instead of checking `GetMessage` directly, since the return value can be `<0` to indicate errors.

Comment: @Default, indeed, but as Raymond Chen points out in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/22/10404367.aspx), `GetMessage()` will never fail when passed the address of a valid `MSG` structure (which we have), with a `NULL` window handle and no message range filter (which we do).